# Dad accidentally sat on my cat

Tags: cats, safety, injury

My dad accidentally sat on my 2.5 kg, 2 year old Persian cat. He didn’t see or hear her because he was on the phone, and she was sleeping on an office chair. Once he sat on her, he realized that something was under him. He stood up, and she ran away.

He didn’t hear her scream, so we don’t know if she got hurt or not, but she was a little pissed at him. Then she got normal even though she was very normal afterwards. Now it’s been almost 8 hours since he sat on her, and she still behaves fine. She ate, then pooped normally and played. She ran around the house and let me pet her and give her treats. She’s walking in a normal way with no sign of pain. She also jumped many times on and off the high bar chair that she loves to sleep on, so I assume no bones are broken.

I’m still worried since my dad told me he sat on her. Is she okay, or should I be concerned? I also checked her breathing pattern and her tongue color. Everything is normal, and there are no signs of internal bleeding. I tried to pick her up and see if she’s in pain to see if she will at least meow, but she didn’t. She seems fine.

I’m sorry if I wrote a lot, but I always worry too much about my cat.

Comment: Sounds like your dad probably didn't put all his weight down, but stood back up the second he felt something under him without fully sitting down first. The feelings of your cat were probably more hurt than her body.

Comment: What does this mean, “Then she got normal even though she was very normal afterwards.”

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I fixed the grammar as best I could (see the edit history), but that part I couldn’t make any sense of. Sorry.

Comment: I’m sorry for the bad grammar english isn’t my first language  but what i meant was she was scared of my dad for some time but then she was playing with him like nothing happened

Comment: "sleeping on an office chair." --> described the padding of the chair's seat.

Comment: Bird bones are much weaker than mammal bones (they are hollow), yet still, if you've ever broken down a whole chicken, you know how amazingly strong even tiny bones actually are.

Answer (score 31):

If she’s behaving completely normally (other than probably avoiding your dad) rather than hiding, walking funny or being lethargic, she’s probably fine. I’d keep an eye on her for the next couple days and take her to a vet if you see *any* strange behavior, but if she’s running and playing as usual, it doesn’t sound like she was hurt.

Comment: I always make a special note to watch my cats posture as they walk and look for a hidden limp, and also if they hide in corners more than normal. But if she's jumping to high usual spots, then yes, she's almost certainly fine.

Answer (score 22):

Cats are surprisingly sturdy creatures. By your description, she doesn't appear to act anyway out of normal. She moves normally, eats normally, acts normally. You can keep eye on her for few days for any changes in normal behavior and take her to vet if she suddenly changes, but by all accounts it seems she is not hurt.

Well, maybe her pride and she might avoid your dad out of principle for a while, but unless she shows signs of being hurt (hiding, being lethargic, meowing when touched, etc.) she should be fine.

I assume your dad didn't put his full weight on her, as by the description it sounds he stood up instantly when he felt her. So she probably has nothing worse than slight distrust towards your dad, easily fixed with some snacks.

Comment: "Cats are surprisingly sturdy creatures" Relevant youtube video by a veterinarian: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OAGfx7eB3gA

Answer (score 10):

If you've ever watched a cat squeeze through an impossibly small hole (of course you have), you can understand that cats have extremely deformable bodies.

[image: cat in ridiculous position]

This means their organs can move out of the way to some degree, and reduce the chance of damage. Really, I'd be surprised if a healthy cat that age would get much of an injury even by someone's full weight on a padded office chair. (A hard surface is another matter. Again if the person were overweight or threw themselves onto the chair it's another matter.)

I'd also like to point out that like humans, cats can get bruises and pull muscles which isn't cause for alarm. But many cats suffer in silence so may not meow when something is wrong. If you give your cat a full-body massage from time to time you will become better at telling what is normal and what isn't.

Comment: yeah, cats are very deformable, there's even been a research proving that cats are more "liquid" than rigid (Ig Nobel Physics Prize award).

Comment: https://www.drgoulu.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Rheology-of-cats.pdf, lol